# Vuejs trying to disable the global component of navbar and footerbar when on certain route

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

This is the code used when on a certain route the header should be replaced by another bar.

HeaderBar Code:

```html
<v-app-navbar>
    <header v-if="DesktopHeader">
        content
    </header>
    <header v-if="otherHeader">
        content
    </header>
</v-app-navbar>
```

```js
mounted () {
    if (this.$nuxt.$route.path === '/page') {
        this.otherHeader = true
        this.DesktopHeader = false
    } else {
        this.DesktopHeader = true
        this.otherHeader = false
    }
}
```

Default layout code:

```html
<template>
    <v-app dark>
        <HeaderBar></HeaderBar>

        content

        <FooterBar v-show="FooterHide"></FooterBar>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

```js
this.$route.path === '/page' ? this.FooterHide  = false : this.FooterHide = true
```

This works on localhost but not when deploying it.

Comment: For the FooterBar when on a certain route should not be replaced but gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, the HeaderBar part is correct FooterBar part was not working. Did the same as I did with the HeaderBar, and it was working. Also did not notice on deployment the route changes from '/page' to '/'page/'.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `this.$route.path` with `this.$nuxt.$route.path`.

Also I would suggest to write it like so:

```js
this.FooterHide = this.$nuxt.$route.path === '/page' ? false : true
```

or even

```js
this.FooterHide = this.$nuxt.$route.path !== '/page'
```